# Editing RelationshipSelector.tpl section of a UserDashboard

Tags: css, custom-templates, user-dashboard, jquery

I'm trying to edit the table row content of the "Your Contacts / Organizations" section of the UserDashboard:

[image]

It appears that this section of the `UserDashboard` is controlled by the `RelationshipSelector.tpl` file. However, when I go to override the `RelationshipSelector.tpl` file, I notice that only the row in the `<th>` is being handled here and the `<tbody>` is not:

[image]

The `<tbody>` is being rendered somewhere and I need to be able to edit the table row inside of it that is of `id="101"`:

[image]

**Question:** Where is the `<tbody>` being handled, so I can pull out the "Edit Contact Information" link and delete the rest of the table?

**Note:** It could also be an escaped character issue too, you can see my different attempts at removing the row and table by escaping the id of 100 (#100), which is perceived as CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section is generated using the [datatable](https://datatables.net/), and data is called using ajax method.

You could use [ajaxsuccess](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) to call after the data is retrieved from ajax.

Comment: ajaxSuccess() did the trick. Much appreciated!